# Wpf Expander with HeaderTemplateSelector bind IsExpanded only to one specific Template

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a templated Expander with a custom header.

I've removed the ToggleButton part so the Header can fill all the top part of the Expander

I have 2 global modes **MidiSenderMode.Play** and **MidiSenderMode.Edit**.

If we are in Play mode the Header will be a button and the Expander will be **always** collapsed no matter if I press it.

If we are in Edit mode I want to bind the **IsExpanded** of the Expander with the **IsChecked** of the ToggleButton.

I've created 2 Templates and a template selector

```
<!--EXPANDER HEADER TEMPLATE(TOGGLE BUTTON)-->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ExpanderHeaderToggleButtonTemplate"
                 DataType="local:MidiSenderModel">
        <ToggleButton 
         Background="{Binding BindsDirectlyToSource=True}">
            <StackPanel>
            <!--CONTENT-->
            </StackPanel>
        </ToggleButton>
      </DataTemplate>



 <!--EXPANDER HEADER TEAMPLATE(BUTTON)-->
     <DataTemplate x:Key="ExpanderHeaderButtonTemplate"
                 DataType="local:MidiSenderModel">
       <Button Background="{Binding BindsDirectlyToSource=True}">
          <StackPanel>
            <!--CONTENT-->
          </StackPanel>
       </Button>
     </DataTemplate>


// TEMPLATE SELECTOR
    public class MidiSenderButtonGadgetTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate PlayModeHeaderTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate EditModeHeaderTeamplate { get; set; }

        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            MidiSenderMode? mode = item == null ? (MidiSenderMode?)null : (MidiSenderMode)item;
            return (mode == null || mode.Value == MidiSenderMode.Play) ? 
             PlayModeHeaderTemplate : EditModeHeaderTeamplate;
        }
    }



<!--TEMPLATE SELECTOR-->
        <local:MidiSenderButtonGadgetTemplateSelector
          x:Key="MidiSenderButtonTemplateSelector"
         EditModeHeaderTeamplate="{StaticResource ExpanderHeaderToggleButtonTemplate}" 
         PlayModeHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ExpanderHeaderButtonTemplate}"/>
```

Is it there a way to bind the IsExpanded with the ToggleButton of the first Template and make it expand only in that case ?

```
<Expander Header="{Binding Mode}" HeaderTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MidiSenderButtonTemplateSelector}" 
IsExpanded="???">
<!--CONTENT-->
</Expander>
```

Comment: Still didn't manage to figure it out. Is it even possible to do so ?

Comment: The correct way to handle this would be to add some logic to your view model. Add a property that is the MidiSenderMode, and data bind your IsExpanded to that property with a value converter. The value converter can check what the MidiSenderMode currently is and return true or false for your header.